# Permission is denied even for the root user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, permissions, root

There are some directories that the root user cannot access due to Permission denied.

```
root@lyria:~# ls -l /disk/ssd14tb/haoki/.cache/ | grep gvfs
ls: cannot access '/disk/ssd14tb/haoki/.cache/gvfs': Permission denied
d?????????  ? ?     ?         ?            ? gvfs
```

This directory is accessible for the owner, though.

```
haoki@lyria:~$ ls -l /disk/ssd14tb/haoki/.cache/ | grep gvfs
dr-x------  2 haoki haoki     0 May 15 11:51 gvfs
```

How to make these folders available for the root user?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems those files are part of a sort of mount made by/for haoki user. Check on this:
The administrator cannot access these files and folders due to how the GNOME Virtual File System works. GVFS is used as a mounting point for some resources such as SFTP and SMB which is established by using FUSE to allow non-privileged users to create their own virtual file systems to access these resources.

Since this filesystem driver is running as a non-privileged user and not as a system kernel with privileged access, filesystems created by FUSE are only accessible to the user using that driver which helps avoid possible complications and as a result, root user access to these files and folders is restricted.

From:
https://support.magnetforensics.com/s/article/Unable-to-view-or-download-some-items-from-Linux-computers

There's a solution to try there as well. But it recommends getting the files from this ?mountpoint? instsead.